# Convert MySQL DATETIME to PHP UNIXTIME

Tags: php, datetime, unix-timestamp

What is the easiest way to conver MYSQL Datetime into PHP UNIXTIME?

Example:

data from mysql is `2012-12-31 23:59:59` then it converted into UNIXTIME.

```
$dateTime = '2012-12-31 23:59:59'; // convert this to unixtime stamp
$unixTime = strtotime($dateTime); // this not work as expected
```

I have tried `strtotime`, but it not work correctly.

Comment: MySQL has a `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` function.

Comment: What's the PHP UNIXTIME type? I've always just stored my timestamps as integers.

Comment: @GBD i edit added sample code.

Comment: @hobbs Nope, this should be done in PHP, not MySQL query

Comment: @WaleedKhan I prefer stored it in DATETIME, so it still readable if i see from MySQL.

Comment: is it typo mistake `$datetime` must be `$dateTime` in your question ?

Comment: @GBD yes it is a typo mistake, sorry about that.

Comment: @GusDeCooL That is a bad reason to choose a data type. In addition, I still don't know what PHP's UNIXTIME is.

Comment: What is `var_dump($unixTime)` ? can you paste it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do:

```
list($date, $time) = explode(' ', $yourMySQLDateTime);
list($year, $month, $day) = explode('-', $date);
list($hour, $minute, $second) = explode(':', $time);

$timestamp = mktime($hour, $minute, $second, $month, $day, $year);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(mydatefield);
```

.

```
$dateTime = '2012-12-31 23:59:59';
$unixTime = new DateTime($dateTime);
echo $unixTime->getTimestamp();
```

Didn't test it, so I'm ready for the downvotes.

Comment: please see the comment on my question, i need it to be done in PHP. not mysql query.

Comment: @GusDeCooL The best way to do it is via MySQL query and not PHP.

Comment: @WaleedKhan Semantically speaking, you want to extract the unix timestamp from the database. Therefore you should design your query to extract the timestamp. In addition, it will probably run marginally faster, though this is more noticeable for queries with several return rows and manipulatory commands.

Comment: If you set `date_default_timezone_set()` properly, your example works and returns the same timestamp as the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

The reason why `strtotime` would not work as expected is because you have to specify the timezone. If your timezone is GMT it would be

```
$dateTime = '2012-12-31 23:59:59';
echo strtotime($dateTime . " GMT")
```